# Alternative to Goto Label in Python?

Tags: python, goto

I know I can't use Goto and I know Goto is not the answer. I've read similar questions, but I just can't figure out a way to solve my problem.

So, I'm writing a program, in which you have to guess a number. This is an extract of the part I have problems:

```
x = random.randint(0,100)    

#I want to put a label here

y = int(raw_input("Guess the number between 1 and 100: "))

if isinstance( y, int ):
    while y != x:
        if y > x:
            y = int(raw_input("Wrong! Try a LOWER number: "))
        else:
            y = int(raw_input("Wrong! Try a HIGHER number "))
else:
    print "Try using a integer number"
    #And Here I want to put a kind of "goto label"`
```

What would you do?

Comment: Change your `int(raw_input(` to `input(` if you have Python 2.x. As for the label, what is the rest of your code? Do you want to call a function?

Comment: In fact, you can ([1](https://github.com/alimsk/goto-python), [2](https://github.com/snoack/python-goto), [3](https://github.com/thautwarm/goto.py)) use `goto` in _Python_, nor do I see why it is never [the answer](https://blog.joren.ga/gotophobia-harmful).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this, but generally you'll want to use loops, and you may want to explore `break` and `continue`. Here's one possible solution:

```
import random

x = random.randint(1, 100)

prompt = "Guess the number between 1 and 100: "

while True:
    try:
        y = int(raw_input(prompt))
    except ValueError:
        print "Please enter an integer."
        continue

    if y > x:
        prompt = "Wrong! Try a LOWER number: "
    elif y < x:
        prompt = "Wrong! Try a HIGHER number: "
    else:
        print "Correct!"
        break
```

`continue` jumps to the next iteration of the loop, and `break` terminates the loop altogether.

(Also note that I wrapped `int(raw_input(...))` in a try/except to handle the case where the user didn't enter an integer. In your code, not entering an integer would just result in an exception. I changed the 0 to a 1 in the `randint` call too, since based on the text you're printing, you intended to pick between 1 and 100, not 0 and 100.)

Answer (score 1):

### Python does not support `goto` or anything equivalent.

You should think about how you can structure your program using the tools python does offer you. It seems like you need to use a loop to accomplish your desired logic. You should check out the [control flow page](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html) for more information.

```
x = random.randint(0,100)
correct = False
prompt = "Guess the number between 1 and 100: "

while not correct:

  y = int(raw_input(prompt))
  if isinstance(y, int):
    if y == x:
      correct = True
    elif y > x:
      prompt = "Wrong! Try a LOWER number: "
    elif y < x:
      prompt = "Wrong! Try a HIGHER number "
  else:
    print "Try using a integer number"
```

In many other cases, you'll want to use a [function](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) to handle the logic you want to use a goto statement for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use infinite loop, and also explicit break if necessary.

```
x = random.randint(0,100)

#I want to put a label here
while(True):
    y = int(raw_input("Guess the number between 1 and 100: "))

    if isinstance( y, int ):

    while y != x:
    if y > x:
        y = int(raw_input("Wrong! Try a LOWER number: "))
    else:
        y = int(raw_input("Wrong! Try a HIGHER number "))
    else:
      print "Try using a integer number"

     # can put a max_try limit and break
```