# Breaking loop to return to beginning and adding further loops

Tags: python

first post here and fairly new to Python; I have used the search function and tried some of the suggestions there,but still struggling.
I'm making a small program that takes a set of numbers and performs simple statistical functions on those numbers without the use of any library's or statistics packages.
The user is asked to enter values and then asked what function they want to apply to the set; I want to return to the beginning when the user selects 4.
Code below - have left out the part for user selecting '4'.
I would also like the user to have a further choice and add another set of numbers, but haven't been able to do this either.

I'm aware this is probably related to indentation or my sloppy code but I'm very much a beginner.

Thanks

```
# Library's used
# none

# Statement to make function work
x=True

# Initial print statements
print( "Please enter a list of numbers...")
print("Enter these individually,hitting enter after each occasion...")

# Main function
while x==True:



  try:
# User input
# This wouldn't be suitable for large lists
# Need something more concise 
     f = int(input('Enter a value: '))
     g = int(input('Enter a value: '))
     h = int(input('Enter a value: '))
     i = int(input('Enter a value: '))
     j = int(input('Enter a value: '))
     k = int(input('Enter a value: '))
     l = int(input('Enter a value: '))
     m = int(input('Enter a value: '))
     n = int(input('Enter a value: '))
     o = int(input('Enter a value: ')) 
     # Values stored here in list
     list1 =[f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o]
     list2 =[f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o]   
     x=True
     # If input produces error (!=int)
  except (ValueError,TypeError,IndexError):
     print ("That was not a valid number.  Try again...")
  else:
     # Variables
     length_list1=len(list1)  # Length     
     list3= [int(i) for i in list1] # Convert list elements to int
     b_sort=sorted(list3) # Sorted ascending
     b_select=((length_list1+1)/2) # Select the middle value
     val_1=b_select-0.5 # Subtracts -0.5 from b_select
     val_2=b_select+0.5 # Add's 0.5 to b_select
     b_median_float=(list3[int(val_1)]+list3[int(val_2)])/2 # Selects values either side of middle value
     mode=max(set(list3),key=list3.count) # Establishes a count of each int in list, largest count stored in variable.
     x=True

    # When the values satisfy the condition
  if (list1==list2):
    print("\nAll values declared")
    print ("You entered",length_list1,"values","\n",list1)
    print("Select a function for your list of numbers\n1.Mean\n2.Median\n3.Mode\n4.New set of numbers\n5.Exit")
    # User prompted for further input

  choice = input('Enter a value (1 to 5): ')


  def b_median():
      # If number of values are odd
      if type(b_select)==float:
        return b_median_float 
        print(b_median_float)
        # If even
      else:
        return print(b_select)
# Variables from calculations
  a=(sum(list3)/length_list1)
  b= b_median()
  c=mode
# Responses to user input
  if (choice=='1'):
        print("The mean is:",a)
        choice=input('Enter a value (1 to 5): ') 
  if (choice== '2'):
        print("The median is:",b)
        choice=input('Enter a value (1 to 5): ')
  if (choice== '3'):
        print("The mode is:",c)
        choice=input('Enter a value (1 to 5): ')
  if (choice=='5'):
      sys.exit()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternative to Goto, Label in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38494761/alternative-to-goto-label-in-python)

Comment: You should always indent with 4 spaces in python.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @Georgy not the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do all what you want with loops.

```
def median(numbers):
    if len(numbers) % 2 == 1:
        return sorted(numbers)[int(len(numbers)/2)]
    else:
        half = int(len(numbers)/2)
        return sum(sorted(numbers)[half-1: half+1])/2
def mode(numbers):
    counts = {numbers.count(i): i for i in numbers}
    return counts[max(counts.keys())]
def read():
    print("Please, enter N: a length of your list.")
    number_count = int(input())
    print("Please, enter all of your numbers")
    numbers = list()
    for i in range(number_count):
        numbers.append(int(input()))
    return number_count, numbers


while True:
    number_count, numbers = read()
    while True:
        print("Please, select an option:\n1 - Median\n2 - Mode\n3 - Exit\n4 - \
New numbers\n5 - Add numbers to existing list\n6 - Print your list")
        option = int(input())
        if option == 1:
            print(median(numbers))
        if option == 2:
            print(mode(numbers))
        if option == 3:
            sys.exit()
        if option == 4:
            break
        if option == 5:
            new_number_count, new_numbers = read()
            number_count += new_number_count
            numbers = numbers + new_numbers
        if option == 6:
            print(numbers)
```

I have some advice for you:

1. Try to write your function in the beginning - it seems clearly.
2. Try to google and use all python capabilities.
3. Give more clearly names to variables.

Good luck in your endeavours.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the part for finding the mode - I can see it works but could you explain the logic behind the function?

Comment: @KyleDavis I make a `dict`, where each key is count of elements `i` in array `numbers` and value is element `i`. If in dict could be duplicate for array [1,1,1] it looks like {3: 1, 3: 1, 3:1}, but in dict can't be duplicate, so we have just {3:1}, where 3 is count and 1 is number. Then we take a max from keys (from counts) and return this value. I think it can be no optimal, but it short = ) If you like, you can search more efficiently code for `mode`.

Comment: @KyleDavis and as you can see, if we have two (or more) numbers with the same count, we will take a last. Because in each step we rewrite value with the same key.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should define the `b_median` and other functions outside the loop.

Your loop works best like this, by setting the `max_size` variable you can ask for as many numbers as you'd like;

```
max_size = 100  # can be as large as you like

# Main function
while x:
    try:
        list1 = []
        for i in range(max_size):
            list1.append(int(input('Enter a value: ')))
        list2 = list(list1)  # copy list1 to list2; see further down why it's super important
    except TypeError:
        # If input produces error (!=int)
        print("That was not a valid number.  Try again...")

    ................

    choice = ''
    while choice != '4':
        choice = input('Enter a value (1 to 5): ')
        if (choice == '1'):
            print("The mean is:", a)
        elif (choice == '2'):
            print("The median is:", b)
        elif (choice == '3'):
            print("The mode is:", c)
        elif (choice == '5'):
            sys.exit()
```

#### The While x loop

As you can notice we changed the `while x==True` to `while x`, that is because, the while-loop will loop while the expression is true, meaning you can write `while True` for an infinite loop. Here we kept your `x` variable but you can remove it and just use `True` directly.

#### The list copy

We will there provide you a quick example of how list copy works in python, because, you will (everyone has) fall into the trap aswell.

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list2 = list1  # we made a "copy" of list1 there

print(list1)  # [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(list2)  # [1, 2, 3, 4]

# seems good to me so far
# Now let's update the list2 a bit

list2[0] = "I love chocolate"

print(list2)  # ['I love chocolate', 2, 3, 4]
print(list1)  # ['I love chocolate', 2, 3, 4]

# whyyyyyy I just changed the value in list2, not in list1 ?!
```

That's because in python, doing `list2 = list1` will make list2 reference the same place in memory as list1, it will clone the list1.

```
id(list1) == id(list2)  # True

# By the way, the id() function will give you the "social security number"
# of whatever you ask for. It should be unique for each element, and when
# it's not, that means those two elements are in fact one.

# That means here, that list2 is like the second name of list1, that's
# why changing one will change both.
```

To avoid this and make a "real" copy we use the syntax `list2 = list(list1)` (some other way exists).

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list2 = list(list1)  # we made a copy of list1 there

id(list1) == id(list2)  # False, that means the two lists are different

print(list1)  # [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(list2)  # [1, 2, 3, 4]

list2[0] = "I love chocolate"

print(list2)  # ['I love chocolate', 2, 3, 4]
print(list1)  # [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice that's really helpful - especially the list advice!